# Can ClickHouse ignore & return failed rows when batch inserting?

Tags: clickhouse

Occasionally we get failed inserts, and I was wondering if it's possible to get clickhouse to ignore the failing inserts and return them, rather than failing the entire batch.

This may be a dumb requirement. You could argue that there should be no failing inserts, but I was wondering if it was possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best option might be to send small batches using async inserts as @tyler-hannan suggested. This would at least allow you to ascertain the failed rows. Your mileage here will depend on the type of failure you're encountering - you can be sure the insert is completed with https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/operations/settings/settings/#wait-for-async-insert.